# Close a control when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a custom datepicker control inside a grid `<editor template>`.  It does not close and return to the grid when user presses enter or escape.

I have the JavaScript code for trapping the enter key, but I need the next line of JavaScript that will close the control and return to the grid.

At present, I can only close the control by clicking on another control or by clicking once inside the control, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> works.

Looking for JavaScript that will provide same function for keyboard as mouse.

Comment: I guess you will have to show some code/markup (of the datepicker control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Third-party vendor ultimately provided a function to close the editor template control and return to the grid.

Comment: Choose this as the answer so this question can be closed/ignored.

Comment: Or better, remove it. It's useless.

Comment: Help me out here -- I tried to read the doc on this forum -- how do you delete a post?  I would have happily done that.

I will mark it answered.